# FPGA SPI controller ADC + posedge/negedge constraints

Tags: fpga, spi, xilinx, vivado, artix-series-fpga

I want to implement the SPI controller for an ADC and have the following timing diagram :
[image: Timing diagram ADC]

I'm implemented an FPGA controller that works on posedge clock, detecting the data coming from DOUT pin (it is generated on negedge -no problem). However, my generated address is not being properly detected by the ADC. It looks like the address is shifted, which could indicate that my timing constraints might be not adequate.
Datasheet gives me the setup/hold time (t4,t5).

How can I give an adequate output_delay constraint, knowing that address is generated in the same edge that it is supposed to be detected?

I'm working in XDC (Xilinx Artix 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when doing SPI, you try to separate sampling and driving edges. This ensures that hold time is met, at the expense of setup time.

For DIN (host controller MOSI) you have a few options for this.

- Use sdc `set_output_delay` constraint to specify SCK to MOSI min/max hold time. The P&R tool will then add delay to MOSI.
- Insert a 1/2 cycle delay on MOSI. Best done using an I/O placed flop clocked on the opposite edge. Probably don't need to constrain it then. While you're at it, use an ODDR to make SCK.
- Use a PLL / MMCM to make an additional clock phase to clock MOSI later relative to SCK. Again, consider using an ODDR to make SCK.

Here's something from Xilinx Community (fun fact: there I'm vortex1601): https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D52E00006iHjFySAK/source-synchronous-vs-system-synchronous-bidirectional-spi?language=en_US

Finally, note that SPI has four different modes: two variations of 'clock phase' (CPHA) and two variations of 'clock polarity' (CPOL). Make sure the SPI mode your ADC requires matches up with your controller. From your diagram, it looks like you want CPOL=1 and CPHA=1, so Mode 3.

SPI Modes:

[image]

From here: https://www.corelis.com/education/tutorials/spi-tutorial/

That said, Xilinx has SPI controller IP, here: https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/axi_quadspi.html This IP supports single, dual, or quad bit modes, and it deals with the different clock modes.